# Printing HTML using servlet vs using a jsp. What are their Advantages?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

What are the advantages of printing a HTML page using a servlet instead of using a jsp

```
<pre>
out.println("<html><body>");
out.println("<h1>My HTML Body</h1>");
out.println("</html></body>");
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

writing html with servlets is very  cumbersome , that's why jsp was developed . internally though jsp are transformed into  a servlet by the container so we don't have to write all those `out.println(...some html);` our self . 
jsp also allows us to seperate out logic from our views.

Comment: correlary:  it allows a clear separation of the view from the controller.  If you're writing your views via java code in the servlet, the servlet becomes both the view and the controller.  In addition, i'd also caution against executing anything in JSP code other than rendering the data provide by the servlet to the view.  Doing so makes the view part controller, which is not a great idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a lot of Java code, for example getting data from database, security, validation, etc, you may put this logic into servlet. For printing just HTML you may use JSP, or just static HTML page. It depends on your needs.

Comment: Can you please give me an example..?